CMake Error -Cannot specify link libraries for target "conan_test" which is not built by this project
I am new to c++ and trying to install mongocxx through conan on clion (I installed the clion conan plugin). I installed conan already with homebrew and installed mongocxx-driver with the plugin and once i run my cmake it returned
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (target_link_libraries):
Cannot specify link libraries for target "conan_test" which is not built by
this project.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(conan_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


find_package(mongocxx)


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mongo::mongocxx_static)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

I want to be able to include in my main.cpp the mongo-cxx dependency.

you need to swap the order of the two lines target_link_libraries and add_executable, can you do that and tell us if there is still an error ?

I solved it:
New CMakeLists.txt for whoever got stuck with same error:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(conan_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(mongocxx REQUIRED)

# Add your executable first
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# Then, link your executable or library with the corresponding package targets
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mongo::mongocxx_static)

